# Gradual color change on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm a beginner who wants to learn properly how to write code. The following code takes initial RGB values and gradually changes them (shade by shade) to targeted rgb values, scroll by scroll. The code works, but is there a way to clean this code, and get the same gradual result?

```
//GRADUALLY CHANGE BACKGROUND COLOR WHILE SCROLLING

//function parameters:
//ElemId: targeted element
//r1,g1,b1: starting color
//r2,g2,b2: finishing color
//scrollFromTop (in px): how much scrollTop until complete color change. can element height value too.

function changeColor(ElemId, r1, g1, b1, r2, g2, b2, scrollFromTop) {
     //get scroll length till complete color change
     //this specifically makes colors change completely when you scroll to the bottom.
     //Instead, you could make scrollFromTop pixel-specific, by deleting this below,
     //and directly adding the wanted argument to the funtion's scrollFromTop parameter.
     var pageHeight = document.getElementById(ElemId).scrollHeight;
     var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;
     var scrollFromTop = pageHeight - windowHeight;


     //get difference between two colors
     function diff(a, b) {
         return Math.abs(a - b);
     }
     var redDiff = diff(r1, r2);
     var greenDiff = diff(g1, g2);
     var blueDiff = diff(b1, b2);

     //get unit (shade) by which the color will change by one scroll
     var redUnit = redDiff / scrollFromTop;
     var greenUnit = greenDiff / scrollFromTop;
     var blueUnit = blueDiff / scrollFromTop;


     $(document).scroll(function () {
         //get value of scrollTop each time you scroll
         var scrollTopVal = $(document).scrollTop();

         //add or subtract r,g,b shades when scrolling. Example:
         //subtract if going from rgb(255,255,255) to rgb(0,0,0)
         //add if going the other way
         function direction(x, y, Unit) {
             if (x < y) {
                 return Math.round(x + (Unit * scrollTopVal));
             } else {
                 return Math.round(x - (Unit * scrollTopVal));
             }
         }

         //IF makes sure new target color stays after certain point
         //ELSE changes color shades step by step using the "direction" function as we scroll
         if (scrollTopVal > scrollFromTop) {
             //rgb string
             var rgb = "rgb(" + r2 + ", " + g2 + ", " + b2 + ")";
             $("#" + ElemId).css("background", rgb);
         } else {
             var newRed = direction(r1, r2, redUnit);
             var newGreen = direction(g1, g2, greenUnit);
             var newBlue = direction(b1, b2, blueUnit);

             var rgb = "rgb(" + newRed + ", " + newGreen + ", " + newBlue + ")";
             $("#" + ElemId).css("background", rgb);
         }
     });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
     changeColor("container", 51, 60, 98, 111, 195, 169);
});
```

For HTML and CSS, or to see the code in action, go [here](http://codepen.io/amirtatin/pen/dOPebo?editors=0010).